# Conflict between two network interfaces eth0 and eth1

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I have a computer connected to the router and the PS2 is connected to a computer. When the PS2 off, the computer connects to the Internet, and everything works fine. But when the PS2 is turned on and connected to the computer, suddenly the computer is disconnected from the network, and I can not browse the Internet, check email, etc.

How can I fix this, so when PS2 was on computer still has connection to internet ?

Log when computer connected to internet and PS2 is off:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-pc:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

ubuntu@ubuntu-pc:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00
          inet addr:192.168.1.48  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::beae:c5ff:fe17:e4ba/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1095 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1184 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:446111 (446.1 KB)  TX bytes:168890 (168.8 KB)
          Interrupt:18 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:93 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:14040 (14.0 KB)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:772 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:772 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:65187 (65.1 KB)  TX bytes:65187 (65.1 KB)
```

Log when computer disconnects from internet and PS2 is on:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-pc:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

ubuntu@ubuntu-pc:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.1.48  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::beae:c5ff:fe17:e4ba/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1286 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1394 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:468580 (468.5 KB)  TX bytes:188872 (188.8 KB)
          Interrupt:18 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::beae:c5ff:fe17:e689/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:105 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:261 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12038 (12.0 KB)  TX bytes:37307 (37.3 KB)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:874 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:874 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:73682 (73.6 KB)  TX bytes:73682 (73.6 KB)
```

Network config file:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-pc:/etc/network$ cat interfaces 
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Can anyone help how to resolve this?

Problem solved. Correct routing table should look like this:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-pc:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1
192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu!  **;-)** So your PC has 2 NICs, The PlayStation2 is plugged into `eth1` and `eth0` on the the PC is plugged into a DHCP router/modem and your PC is a DHCP server as well???

Comment: Yes it is.  My PC has 2 intergated NICs on motherboard, The PlayStation2 is plugged into eth1 and eth0 on the the PC is plugged into a DHCP router and my router is a DHCP server.

Comment: Is your PC a DHCP server as well???

Comment: No, router is DHCP server.

Comment: But the router isn't connected to the PS2, so it cannot give it an IP address...  Why don't you connect the PS2 to the router directly instead of going through the PC?  (Not that it's impossible, but you will need to set static IP addresses on both the PC's secondary NIC and the PS2 outside of the DHCP range)